# form posting correct value action getting null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Ok, I'm new to MVC and am frying some brain understanding this.

I have a view with a form and several inputs, all placed with HtmlHelpers, some from a model with validation and an action which accepts all the inputs as parameteres. The parameters are all int,string,DateTime and decimal.

With firebug I can attest that all the parameters are being posted correctly and with the breakpoint on the action entry I can see all parameters filled correctly.

All but ***one.***
This is a required parameter and for some reason it is arriving at the controller with a null value. This parameter is rendered with @Html.TextBoxFor and has *[Required]* on the model.

I'm kinda lost here, so any help is appreciated

Edit: Action Signature: `public ActionResult Create(int forn, int pro, string URLPR_LEI, decimal VLPRO_LEI, DateTime DTINI_LEI, decimal VLFRE_LEI, bool first, bool fast, bool free, bool buyback)`

The textbox giving problems is created as follows:
`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VLPRO_LEI)`

And the model:

```
    [Required]
    public decimal VLPRO_LEI { get; set; }
```

I have other itens exactly as this one (VLFRE_LEI) which is working fine

Edit2: Ok, i found out what was the problem. The unobstrusive validator requires a **.** to separate the decimal value, however the action sees it as null because of the dot. Using integers is fine apparently

Do I have to disable validation for decimal values or there is a work around?

Comment: could you post the view code, controller and model? . just snippets of whats required.

Comment: Could you post the method signature for your action, and the HTML for your input field?

Comment: try having a look at the formcollection thats coming back to see if the framework is receiving the value.   Then you can see if its the model binding that's losing the value or not

Comment: Is the value posted for `VLPRO_LEI` something that can be converted to a `decimal`?  Also, you say the value is null, did you mean zero because decimal isn't a nullable type?

Comment: @ChrisFulstow I was getting an exception on post, so I made the parameter nullable to check it out and it was a null, check the second edit please.

Comment: on Request.Form["VLPRO_LEI"] I can see the value, it just isn't hitting as a parameter....

Comment: @Thiago that'd definitely indicate a problem at the model binder, it's having trouble converting the string to a decimal, probably because of the locale settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this might be a model binding issue related to locale, check out this blog post:

- [Model Binding Decimal Values](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx)

Comment: Even though the method described in the answer did not work for me I'm fully convinced the problem is locale related, the way I was able to fix was getting the value as string from Request.Form["VLPRO_LEI"] and using Convert.ToDecimal with CultureInvariant

Answer (score 0):

One reason this can happen is if the model has a private setter on the property you are wanting updated

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed [HttpPost] above the action which is the Action for the post.

Ex:

```
[HttpPost]
public string SomeFunction(){
}
```

the above function "SomeFunction()" is the post function from the form.

when posting you should use [HttpPost]
while setting the ActionResult to the View you should use [HttpGet]